# Force re-signing of kernel and modules for Secure Boot?

Tags: 18.04, secure-boot

I accidentally hit `reboot` and the next boot failed signatures in Secure Boot. I disabled secure boot to get back in.

How can I force re-signing of everything so that secure boot can be enabled again?

Comment: Yes, if you know which kernel modules have signature problems... I can't tell you specifically how to do this... but I **do** know that it's a real PITA. Best just to leave Secure Boot off.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I imagine there _has_ to be some tool out there which is called before reboot like the installer says, but I can't seem to find it.